# How to send a signal from a qtableWidget horizontal header?

Tags: python, header, pyqt5, signals, qtablewidget

I want to remove a row from a qtableWidget when selecting an horizontal header.
I tried the following command but it's not working with pyqt5 :

```py
tableWidget.horizontalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(MyCallable)
```

In fact, Qt documentation does not mention this signal for a qTableWidget. So I am looking for an equivalent function i.e a function that will send a notification when an horizontal header is selected.

Below, a reproducible example :

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(350, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 300, 200))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
# =============================================================================
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(self.call)
# =============================================================================
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 200, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Surname"))
        it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("John")
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, it)
        it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Heen")
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, it)
        it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Mark")
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, it)
        it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Thomson")
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, it)

    def call(self):
        print("row selected")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui        = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You probably want to connect to `self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().sectionClicked` instead of `self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().sectionClicked`

Comment: Okay I am confuzzled -- your MRE works fine for me I think -- when I click the header it prints "row selected" so what is not happening on your end and/or I am using Python 3.7  with pyqt5 on Win10 -- what are you using?

Comment: @Heike answered my question.  In fact, I thought that horizontalHeader is for headers that help to identify rows content while it is to identify columns content. Thank you for your answers.